What day of the year was the leap day at the start of the Julian calendar?
In our modern era the leap day is February 29th, but was that the case when the Julian calendar first went into effect?  I read the Inter Gravissimas and it refers to leap day as the bisextile day.  But that is unclear to me, so I would appreciate an explanation of the meaning behind the word 'bisextile'. Here is the relevant excerpt mentioning leap day prior to 1582.

Then, lest the equinox recede from XII calends April [March 21st] in the future, we establish every fourth year to be bissextile (as the custom is), except in centennial years ;  which always were bissextile until now; we wish that year 1600 is still bissextile; after that, however, those centennial years that follow are not all bissextile, but in each four hundred years, the first three centennial years are not bissextile, and the fourth centennial year, however, is bissextile, so the years 1700, 1800 and 1900 will not be bissextile.  Assuredly, the year 2000, as with our custom, will have a bissextile intercalation, February will contain 29 days, and the same rule of intermittent bissextile intercalations in each four hundred year period will be preserved in perpetuity.

So my question is, what day of the year was leap day in 45 BC?
Also, I would like ancient sources that provide the answer.

If the relevant Wikipedia article doesn't answer the question sufficiently, please edit to explain what you're looking for. The footnoted sources aren't the best, but it explains that the date was essentially Feb 24/March 1.
